# Check how many times other website redirects using php?

Tags: php

for ex: google pagespeed insights
Click

[here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

how can we count the page redirection of other page using in php?
i have tried alot but not got anything. please help me

Answer (score 0):

First make track.php with this code or similar:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["url"])) {
    $url = $_REQUEST["url"];
} else {
    // Error url is not set
    exit();
}
// Your count code here to store in database
$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "user", "password", "database");
$url = $mysqli->real_escape_string($url); // For security
$mysqli->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO tracks ('%s');", $url));

// Redirect
header("Location: " . $url);
```

Now you can call your url like this: http://yoursite/track.php?url=https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/